# Get Quater using number as input in MySql

Tags: mysql

i have a column that has month number stored as integer. i would like to create a new column with the quater of each month. is there an simpler way of doing the same, i have to use this in multiple places. so just wanted to check if there is any simpler way of doing this.

currently i am using below to achieve it

```
case when tt1.resolved_month in (1,2,3) then 1
     when tt1.resolved_month in (4,5,6) then 2
     when tt1.resolved_month in (7,8,9) then 3
     when tt1.resolved_month in (10,11,12) then 4
end as quater
```

i checked the [Quarter](https://database.guide/quarter-examples-mysql/) function and it doesnt support number as input.

Comment: it's better to add a `month2quater` function in the application logic than saving redundant data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CEIL` function will get the quarter.

```
SELECT CEIL(resolved_month / 3) AS quarter
```

Demonstration:

```
Month   Month/3   Quarter
-------------------------
1       0.3333      1
2       0.6667      1
3       1           1
4       1.3333      2
5       1.6667      2
6       2           2
7       2.3333      3
8       2.6667      3
9       3           3
10      3.3333      4
11      3.6667      4
12      4           4
```

[Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d920a3/1)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `case` expression, you could divide the month by 3 and `ceil` the result:

```sql
SELECT CEIL(resolved_month / 3) AS quarter
FROM   tt1
```

As @exudong suggested in the comments, it may be a good idea to encapsulate this logic in a function and re-use it wherever needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `QUARTER()` function:

```
SELECT 
   resolved_month, 
   QUARTER(ADDDATE('2021-01-01',INTERVAL resolved_month-1 MONTH)) as quarter2
FROM months;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d920a3/6)

The advantage () is that everybody who read this will recognize that the quarter is being calculated.